# Why is the queue receiving the subscription event, but not my program?

Tags: events, subscription, solace

Both the Solace queue and my program are subscribing to `#LOG/INFO/SUB_ADD/DEVICE/ID/123`.
When a new device which connects and subscribe to `DEVICE/ID/123`, both of them can successfully receive the subscribe event.

But, if I set subscription as `#LOG/INFO/SUB_ADD/DEVICE/ID/>`, only the solace queue receives the event.

Why can't my program receive the subscription event? 
The problem persists even after my program sets it's subscription to `#LOG/>`.

Comment: Please confirm that there are 3 separate devices here. The queue on the router, your custom program listening to "#LOG/>" and a third device that connects and subscribes to `DEVICE/ID/123`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem here is that there is an ACL rule preventing your application to subscribe to one or more topics in `#LOG/INFO/SUB_ADD/DEVICE/ID/>`. This can be easily verified with `show log acl subscribe-topic`.

If this is not the case, please revert back with the CLI outputs of `show client <client-name> stats detail` and `show client <client-name> subscriptions` to look further into the issue.